# What happens to coins collected by rabbids?

Tags: mario-plus-rabbids-kingdom-battle

During a normal battle, coins often drop.

These coins can be collected, and they are added to your wallet as far as I know. You can also pick them up after the battle.

But enemy rabbids can also collect coins during a battle. They don't seem to particularly go for it, but they often just run over them.

Does something special happen with the coins collected by enemy rabbids? Do they collect them for you? Is a coin collected by an enemy rabbid lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [this GameInformer article](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2017/08/29/10-invaluable-beginner-s-tips-for-mario-rabbids-kingdom-battle.aspx), yes, enemies will take any coins they run over and you cannot get these coins.

> Enemies will also nab the coins if they run over them first, so make sure you collect them as soon as possible – if you can, you may even want to save one character's movement phase for the end of your turn just to ensure you can pick up any stray coins.

Comment: It's important to note that you can use Beep-0 to collect the coins too, just by moving your cursor over them, so long as the coins remain during your turn!